# Custom variable in module

Tags: php, joomla

How can I create custom variable in helper.php file set it right here and use it in tmpl file? Example:

in helper.php I add variable

```
 $customstring = 'My string';
```

Then I want to display this variable in i.e tmpl/default.php

```
<?php echo $customstring; ?>
```

Not working. What's wrong here?

Comment: not used joomla for a while but have you checked how the variables are passed to the view, most mvc patterns use extract() within the template class, on an array or a data object so you need to check some other modal and see how the the data is passed, most likely an array, but defo not striate variable assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your helper file should contain a function or class and should return the result(s) you want to pass back.

If your module's main file is similar to the mod_weblinks.php file
You populate your variable like so

```
$list = modWeblinksHelper::getList($params);
```

and $list is in scope and automatcally available to you within your view and its tmpl files.

If your module is more complex then have a look through some of the other modules within the site.

Answer (score 0):

Include your helper in the main module file (mod_mymodule.php) and then call the right function and use the variable in the view, this is an example:

http://blog.joomlaearth.com/2012/create-you-first-joomla-1-6-module-completely-from-scratch/